# Unregister touch sprite when background scene is zoom and moving

Tags: android, andengine, isometric

I am new to game development on Android, I use AndEngine framework. I'm developing an application with isometric view, at this time I had problems with touchlistener area on the sprite in the scene background, I intend to turn off the touch function on the sprite when the background is shifted, so as not to disturb the background when being moved. How it works?